# Finding Cumulative Distribution Function of weighted data

Tags: r, ggplot2, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have census tract data where each row holds the population size and a variable value (e.g., income). I want to plot the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the TRUE population, i.e., accounting for the population size in each tract.
So if my data has ~3000 census tracts, the entire population is ~ 8 milion.

I tried converting the data to a long form, but the result is a very large DF that is hard to plot and analyse (my real data have ten years of data, so it creates a DF with 80 milion rows).

Here is a sample data and the long form version I tried:

```
df = data.frame(PopSize = rnorm(20,1000,300),
                Income  = rnorm(20,100,30))
df_long = df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), times=df$PopSize),]
```

This  converts the 20 rows with a sample size of ~1000 in each, to a DF with ~20,000 rows, making it impracticle to work with in my real data of ~8 milion.

Is there a way to create a CDF plot that will account for tha sample size in each row?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF), describes at every $x$ point (income in this case), the proportion of the population that is less or equal to that $x$ value. It doesn't matter whether your data has one row per observation, or each row groups multiple observations. It can still be calculated.

Basing the equation off the [Wikipedia page notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) the ECDF is:

$$
\hat F_n(x) = \frac{\text{number of elements}<x}{n}
$$

- $n$ is constant, and in your example is `sum(df$PopSize)`
- the number of elements less than $x$ is the cumulative sum of `df$PopSize` less than $x$

In `R` language:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(PopSize = rnorm(20,1000,300),
                Income  = rnorm(20,100,30))
df <- df[order(df$Income),]
plot(
  x = c(0, cumsum(df$Income)) # 0 because your x variable is a population
  , y = c(0, cumsum(df$PopSize)/sum(df$PopSize))
  , type = "s"
  , xlim = c(0, sum(df$Income))
  , ylim = c(0, 1)
)
```

[image]